# Как мне обработать стили CSS в JSP при отображении, чтобы исправить выравнивание?

Tags: css, jsp

При [тестировании](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication) файлов `JSP` у меня возникает проблема с отображением на экране из-за выравнивания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой пример файла `JSP`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <%@include file="/includes/head.jsp"%>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgba(26, 35, 115, 0.47);
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="text-center vsc-initialized">
<%@include file="/includes/header.jsp"%>
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <main role="main" class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Welcome</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">to</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Project Management</h1>
        <h1 class="cover-heading">System</h1>
    </main></div>
<%@include file="/includes/footer.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно получить результат по типу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы текст был выровненный по центру без конфигурационного заголовка вверху.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать мне, пожалуйста, это проблема `CSS` или `JSP` в целом? Нужно ли что-то исправить в `JSP`, чтобы получить другой результат отображения?

Если нужна дополнительная информация, я готов обновить этот вопрос.

Я ценю любые рекомендации/идеи здесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не в `css`, а в *способе отображения*.

После того, как изменил `путь` и способ отображения в `application.properties`:

вместо:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/jsp/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

заменил на:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

и соответственно расположение `JSP` файлов вместо:

```
/resources/templates/jsp/
```

на:

```
/webapp/
```

проблема с выравниванием при использовании `CSS` стилей в `JSP` была исправлена.